# How to fix? ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version is older than compile-time version

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, python-import, importerror, pycurl

I have this error when I run tests on a conda environment which I built from specs in `environment.yml`

```
File "utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pycurl
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.29.0) is older than compile-time version (7.55.1)
```

The environment.yml file used to build the conda env:

```
name: indices_python
channels:
- defaults
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- coverage 
- coveralls
- nco
- netcdf4
- nose
- numba
- numpy
- pandas
- pycurl
- pynco
- python=3
- scipy
```

The command I'm running (on Linux):

```
$ python -W ignore -m unittest tests/test_*.py
```

How can I fix this and/or how to prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Following fixed it for me

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir --ignore-installed pycurl==7.43.0.2
```

Comment: Thx. Very painfull bug!

Comment: it'd be nice it this answer had information on getting the latest version number of pycurl. I have the exact same error as the OP, but for the version numbers.

Comment: Add this: https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/#history

Answer (score 0):

my solution as follow:
just reinstall curl in your machine:

this link is very good, please [Install curl From Source](https://noknow.info/it/os/install_curl_from_source)